# Unlinked exchanges while importing from excel

Tags: brightway

I am currently trying to import the inventory from excel. I matched the names with ecoinvent 3.8 database and excel template to brightway2 format.

[image: here]

However, all my biosphere flows are unlinked together with some exchanges from ecoinvent. The differences are [image: shown here]

I could not understand what reference product meant and which location must be inserted for biosphere flows.

Could someone please help me understand where the difference is coming from and how I should go about it? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the [linking algorithm](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/master/bw2io/utils.py#L9) matches on all these fields:

- "name"
- "categories"
- "unit"
- "reference product"
- "location"

It looks to me that your biosphere flows aren't linking because they are missing the `category` field (there are multiple biosphere flows, one for each category). You can fix this by either adding the biosphere flow codes (then you match only on code, not other fields), or by including the `categories`. Note that categories are stored as a tuple, and brightway uses `::` to separate the tuple elements, so `('foo', 'bar')` would become `foo::bar` in your CSV or Excel.

Your technosphere flows are linking because you don't specify the `reference product`. This fails to match because the background database does specify the `reference product`, so these attributes aren't the same. You can try to fix that by doing `my_importer.match_database("ecoinvent 3.8_cutoff", fields=["name", "unit", "location"])`, i.e. not matching on the reference product.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response!

After linking the ecoinvent database according to fields  the remaining unlinked technosphere exchanges  were the result of using reference product name for transport activities instead of activity name. 

For a general understanding: If the activity location does not match with the ecoinvent location - is it correct to understand that we have to make the copy of the exchange with a required location for our inventory?

Comment: If you are taking inputs from ecoinvent (or any other database), the location should match, as you are copying the values from that database. If you are building your own inventories, then of course some things won't match. But this is not a software question, it is up to you to determine how best to model your system with the data available.

Comment: that is true! thank you for answering nonetheless.